# C# connecting to an already paired device using 32feet.NET

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth-lowenergy, 32feet

I am trying to connect to a Blood Pressure Machine via bluetooth. The device is already paired with my laptop. When I use nuget pacage inTheNet. I am able to get a list of devices near by, but am unable to get the device that is already paired

```
  string macAddress = FindMACAddress();
        _blueToothEndPoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(BluetoothAddress.Parse(macAddress), BluetoothService.BluetoothBase);
        _blueToothClient = new BluetoothClient(_blueToothEndPoint);
        BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = _blueToothClient.DiscoverDevices();            
            foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo device in devices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(device.DeviceAddress);
        }
```

Comment: How FindMACAddress() is implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone need more fast solution use:

```
public BluetoothDeviceInfo[] DiscoverDevices(int maxDevices, bool authenticated, bool remembered, bool unknown);
```

Where:
*maxDevices* - The number of in-range devices to find before the inquiry may be stopped early. The result can contain more than this number of devices.
*authenticated* - True to return previously authenticated/paired devices.
*remembered* - True to return remembered devices.
*unknown*-True to return previously unknown devices.

Example:

```
var devices = bluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices(10, true, true, false);
 foreach (var device in devices)
            {
                var blueToothInfo =
                    string.Format(
                        "- DeviceName: {0}{1}  Connected: {2}{1}  Address: {3}{1}  Last seen: {4}{1}  Last used: {5}{1}",
                        device.DeviceName, Environment.NewLine, device.Connected, device.DeviceAddress, device.LastSeen,
                        device.LastUsed);
                blueToothInfo += string.Format("  Class of device{0}   Device: {1}{0}   Major Device: {2}{0}   Service: {3}",
                Environment.NewLine, device.ClassOfDevice.Device, device.ClassOfDevice.MajorDevice,
                 device.ClassOfDevice.Service);
                Console.WriteLine(blueToothInfo);
                Console.WriteLine(); 
                devicesList.Items.Add(new BluetoothDeviceInfoContainer(device));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with the device.Remembered property.

```
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices;

foreach (var device in devices)
{

if (device.Remembered == true) return "Already Paired";
else return "Not Paired";

}
```

Hope this helps!

Chris